# Adjust Abaqus .env file to startup with different default number format

Tags: python, format, abaqus

I would like to get Abaqus to load up with all the right setting so I don't have to adjust it eveytime I open it. I currently added the following to my .env file which opens it up with the correct font but I can't figure out how to open up with the correct number format (which I would like it to be in decimal). This is for version 6.14.

```
def onCaeStartup():
    session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].viewportAnnotationOptions.setValues(
        legendFont='-*-verdana-medium-r-normal-*-*-180-*-*-p-*-*-*',
        titleFont='-*-verdana-medium-r-normal-*-*-180-*-*-p-*-*-*',
        stateFont='-*-verdana-medium-r-normal-*-*-180-*-*-p-*-*-*')
```

Answer (score 3):

Turns out its easier then scripting. Just make all your settings in the visualization module that you want then go to "file" >> "Save Display Options" >> "home" and it will always open up with those settings.